# Extract outer div using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

If the HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="div1">
<p>hello</p>
<p>hi</p>
    <div class="nesteddiv">
        <p>one</p>
        <p>two</p>
        <p>three</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I extract just

```
<div class="div1">
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hi</p>
</div>
```

I already tried `parser.find('div', 'div1')` but I'm getting the whole div including the nested one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually want to *[`extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Removing%20elements)* the *nested* `div` from the document and then *get* the first `div`. Here is an example (where `html` is the HTML you provided in the question):

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.div.div.extract()
<div class="nesteddiv">
<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p>three</p>
</div>
>>> soup.div
<div class="div1">
<p>hello</p>
<p>hi</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just find() the nested div and then remove it from the tree using extract()?

Comment: But I need the outer one though.

Comment: extract() actually performs removal, if you extract() the inner layer, you end up with the outer one

Comment: This is correct. My answer highlights this with a working example.